# "Reconfiguring virtual machine" stuck at 100 percent with Terraform

Tags: vmware-vcenter, terraform, sdk

Today at 7:11 am, I started a terraform build. JWTCVTRNIDB01 is the server.

It cloned successfully. Here is terraform error line 25239

```
2019-04-26T07:22:54.643-0700 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.6.0_x4: 2019/04/26 07:22:54 [DEBUG] Virtual machine "/WTC/vm/DO_NOT_SNAPSHOT/JWTCVTRNIDB01": clone complete (MOID: "vm-312044")
```

At 7:22:55 am, it tried to “reconfigure virtual machine”, and it got to 100 percent, then stopped. Here is terraform error line 25346

```
2019-04-26T07:22:55.654-0700 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.6.0_x4: 2019/04/26 07:22:55 [DEBUG] Reconfiguring virtual machine "/WTC/vm/DO_NOT_SNAPSHOT/JWTCVTRNIDB01"
```

This chunk keeps repeating

```
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.vsphere.windows (close)", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "provisioner.local-exec (close)"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.consul (close)", waiting for: "consul_keys.db_hosts"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)", waiting for: "consul_keys.db_hosts"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.local-exec (close)", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.remote-exec (close)", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "module.db_servers.output.name", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "module.db_servers.output.ip_address", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
2019/04/26 07:23:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "consul_keys.db_hosts", waiting for: "module.db_servers.output.name"
2019/04/26 07:23:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "provisioner.local-exec (close)"
2019/04/26 07:23:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.vsphere.windows (close)", waiting for: "module.db_servers.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm"
```

After exactly 5 minutes, terraform tried to destroy the machine (as its programmed to do), and that job is at 0 percent.

That first chunk is supposed to have something right after it like (line 14203 on the terraform log, not the error one the regular one):

```
2019-04-25T14:33:41.171-0700 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.6.0_x4: 2019/04/25 14:33:41 [DEBUG] Looking for OS family for guest ID "windows9Server64Guest"
2019-04-25T14:33:41.304-0700 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.6.0_x4: 2019/04/25 14:33:41 [DEBUG] OSFamily: family for "windows9Server64Guest" is "windowsGuest"
2019-04-25T14:33:41.305-0700 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.6.0_x4: 2019/04/25 14:33:41 [DEBUG] Sending customization spec to virtual machine "/WTC/vm/Discovered virtual machine/JWTCVDAACR01"
2019-04-25T14:33:42.691-0700 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.6.0_x4: 2019/04/25 14:33:42 [DEBUG] Powering on virtual machine "/WTC/vm/Discovered virtual machine/JWTCVDAACR01"
```

It’s almost like the vcenter sdk isn’t listening at that second, so it messes everything up. Is there a way to verify that sdk is working properly at each moment? Is there a way to clear out this job from vcenter (I can't cancel the task from the UI), without restarting vcenter entirely?